# Audio activity in the background for a sports application

Tags: ios, swift, audio, background

I have a sports assistant application.
And I need to play sounds at certain points in time (not constantly).

For example, the application pronounces how many kilometers or minutes the user ran.

But as I know, the application must constantly play the sound (silence is prohibited) in the background, otherwise it will be closed.

Is there any way to play audio at indefinite intervals in the background?

*Note:* I watched other questions and everywhere suggest to play silence in the background.

Comment: @Harjot Singh, with pauses.
Audio is played only when the user runs another kilometer or runs for the next minute.

Comment: Looking at your requirement location updates background makes more sense than audio play mode. You can use either `monitorSignificantLocationUpdate` or `startLocationUpdate` depending on what exactly you wanna achieve and then add distance filter to get the call back when user runs specific distance. Play the audio every time iOS invokes your app